# How I use Regex pattern in HTML text input to validate phone number

Tags: html, regex, validation

My number format as shown in the below:

**1.** 775645645 (9 digits)

**2.** 0775645645 (10 digits)

**3.** +94775645645

The numbers can start with 7 or 0 or +94.

So I tried it with regex pattern in HTML text input as shown in the below:

```
<input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" pattern ="(?:7|0|(?:\+94))[0-9]{9,10}$" required />
```

But this pattern is not working for me. Appreciate your help.

**UPDATE:**

Here Im using jQuery validate to validate a front end form.

Comment: You start by matching one character (7 or 0), then you should only match 8 or 9 digits at the end to get a total of 9 to 10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate phone numbers using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex)

Comment: You must post the code, else, you will attract even more downvotes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
pattern="(?:7|0\d|\+94\d)\d{8}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cTCRBE/2). It will be compiled into a pattern like `^(?:(?:7|0\d|\+94\d)\d{8})$` and will match

- `^(?:` - start of string and the non-capturing group start
- `(?:7|0\d|\+94\d)` - `7`, or `0` and a digit or `+94` and a digit
- `\d{8}` - eight digits
- `)$` - end of the group, end of string.

See the demo below:

```css
input:valid {
  color: navy
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" pattern="(?:7|0\d|\+94\d)\d{8}" required />
  <input type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick responce. But it doesn't works for me. That mean when I add incorrect information into the text field its not validate and I can submit the form. Sir, may I know is there anything do I miss?

Comment: @user3733831 You cannot submit invalis input, see my demo.

Comment: Yes Sir, I checked your demo, its working perfectly. But in my case I can submit the form with invalid input..

Comment: Sir, There was one more thing I could not say when asked the question. Here Im using [jQuery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate a front end form. Probably it would be the issue..

Comment: @user3733831 then please provide a codepen to repro.

Answer (score 1):

Can try this hope it helps

- if it starts with 7, the length must be 9 digits
- if it starts with 0, the length must be 10 digits
- if it starts with +94, the length must be 12 digits

```css
input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid{
  background-color:pink;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="mobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number" pattern ="(7[0-9]{8}|0[0-9]{9}|\+94[0-9]{9})$" required />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is also having issue with  [jQuery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a regex pattern that only works for your examples try this:

```
(?:(?:7|0[1-9]{1})|(?:\+94))[0-9]{8}
```

- `7|0[1-9]{1}` accepts 7 or 0 and one other digit between 1-9
- the `|` is used to represent the "OR" condition
- `\+94` accepts +94 as the 3 beginning digits
- `[0-9]{8}` means 8 other digits between 0 and 9

If you are looking for a pattern that could work for a wide range of phone number patterns, you could try this:

```
^[+]?[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$
```

How this works:

- `^` represents the beginning of the string
- `[+]?` for phone numbers that include "+" at the beginning
- `[(]{0,1}` represents the opening " ( ". For phone numbers that include (###). Example: (222)333-333
- `[0-9]{1,4}` represent the number in between the "(###)"
- `[)]{0,1}` represent the closing ")"
- `[-\s\./0-9]*` this will allow phone numbers to be accepted even if the numbers are divided using "-" or " " or "."
- `$` represents the end of the string

Check this site: https://regexr.com/

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also this regex doesn't seem to do what OP wants. Yours also match `+0`, `(0)`, etc. Seems you just posted a regex for a phone number, ignoring OP's requirements.